# Inertial accelerations like the Coriolis effect are well known. Are there also 'inertial jerks' and what are some examples?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, coriolis-effect, jerk

Inertial accelerations like the Coriolis effect are well known. Are there also 'inertial jerks' and what are some examples?

My guess would be that it would look something like:

$$ j=-3v_r \omega^2 e_r -r \omega^3 e_t $$

Comment: Sure, but usually we'd just call those "time-dependent inertial accelerations".

Answer (score 0):

The Coriolis effect arises when you use co-ordinates fixed in an accelerating frame of reference (in this case, the surface of a rotating planet). If you use co-ordinates fixed in a frame of reference with a more complex motion then this could introduce additional terms that resemble jerks.

Answer (score 0):

An astronaut sits in a rocket on the launch pad. The rocket is launched.

From the astronaut's point of view, the rocket is stationary. A time dependent fictitious force sprang into being and pushed the earth away.